# Image size changing from Expo to App Store

Tags: react-native, app-store, expo

When running my application in Expo all images look fine and lovely, it's just when I deploy to the app store suddenly my images are huge.

I made sure that I follow Expo's standard on image spec as written here;
https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/images/

Even weirder is the images look fine on iPhone X but the size is off on iPhone 7 (but on that same iPhone 7 in Expo everything looks ok). So just wondering if anyone has experienced any issues going from Expo to App Store with images and if they did how did they solve them?

Note: I am yet to deploy to Google play so haven't been able to see the effects there yet.

All input greatly appreciated

Comment: Can confirm Google works just fine

Comment: Did you find out the right path to solve this?

Comment: I had same issue, it was related to the style. Had the images in a container where resizeMode was center and it had to be contain.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use WIDTH and HEIGHT from [Dimensions](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/dimensions/)
And then set width to your image by multiplication of WIDTH on some coefficient.